# How to write a SQL query to get the below Scenario output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 table like below and I need the client_ID from client table and his Roles from roles table, but the condition to get the data the tables is, client whose is having more than one contribution_type.

Please find the below sample table and output.

Client table

```
Client_ID   cname   Contribution_type
-------------------------------------   
   1        A       Regular
   2        B       public 
   3        C       regular
   4        D       private
   1        A       public 
   4        D       similar
```

Role table

```
Client_ID   Rname
------------------    
   1        owner
   2        owner
   3        trustee
   4        benificier
   1        trustee
   2        benificier
   3        owner
   4        owner
```

Output

```
Client_ID   Rname
-------------------    
    1       owner
    1       trustee
    4       beneficiary
    4       owner
```

I've written the below query but getting the below error

```
select 
    c.cid, r.rname 
from 
    Client_table c 
join 
    role_table r on c.cid = r.CID
where 
    c.cid in (select cl.CID, count(Contribution_type) 
              from Client_table c 
              group by cl.CID 
              having count(Contribution_type) > 1);
```

Error message:

> ORA-00913: too many values
>   00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 21 Column: 9

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `count(Contribution_type)` in your `where` subquery. because In only can compare one column.

```
select c.cid,r.rname
from Client_table c 
join role_table r on c.cid = r.CID
where c.cid in (select cl.CID from Client_table c group by cl.CID having count(Contribution_type)>1);
```

or you can just write a subquery in `from` instead of in `where`.

```
select c.cid,r.rname 
from (
  select cl.CID 
  from Client_table c
  group by cl.CID 
  having count(c.Contribution_type)>1
) c 
join role_table r on c.cid = r.CID
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you.
Assuming that in case of same `contribution type` appearing more than once, you want only one instance, use `count (distinct contribution_type)` else just use `count(contribution_type)`

```
select * from role r
where r.client_id in
    (select client_id from client c
    group by client_id 
    having count(distinct contribution_type)>1
    )
```

The reason for the error is that in your `IN` clause, you have mentioned only 1 value, but you are fetching more than 1 values from your subquery, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.cid,r.rname from Client_table c join role_table r on c.cid = r.CID
where c.cid in (select cl.CID from Client_table c group by cl.CID having count(Contribution_type)>1);
```

Remove **count(Contribution_type)** in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

it will do :

```
select  distinct client_id,rname from role_table where client_id in(1,4) order by client_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the subquery is returning multiple columns.  But, you can also simplify the outer query:

```
select r.cid, r.rname 
from role_table r
where r.cid in (select c.CID  -- only one column here
                from Client_table c 
                group by c.CID 
                having count(c.Contribution_type) > 1
               );
```

In other words, you don't need the join to `Client_table` because you have all the fields you need in `role_table`.